# There's something wrong with the blog logo

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, logo

That's actually quite noticeable on the high-resolution screens, the bottom part of the logo is creeping farther than the others.

- Go to the http://blog.stackexchange.com
- Look at the logo:

  > [image]
- Look a bit closer:

  > [image]

Comment: You need to check your eyesight - most people don't browse at that resolution...

Comment: [Go fix it](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/blob/master/images/blog-logo.svg).

Comment: @hich Interesting idea, though I'm away from computer currently. I'll think about it tomorrow.

Comment: I am sure you'd find a way, @nicael - you've made a solid start

Comment: @san Pretty solid, I'd say. Week / month / quarter first rank :)

Comment: Hello close voters; I'm not sure how many times we have to go into this but you not liking something does not make it "off-topic" let alone "primarily opinion based". If you don't understand this set up a chat room and I'll be happy to explain, with examples.

Comment: @hichris123 I've made a pull request!

Comment: Guys, on topic. How is it an opinion - this exists?

Comment: @Tim I don't really get your second sentence...

Comment: Under reasonable circumstances it's non-reproducible, an option under off topic closes. @ben

Comment: Great, now I can't not notice it. >:(

Comment: @Adam I pushed a pull request fixing it, hope it gets approved :)

Comment: @random while silly, nitpicking, [put your own word here], this is still a valid bug report. Voting to reopen while of course casting a downvote.

Comment: You might think it's primarily opinion based, but the original vote was for non-reproducible @sha

Comment: @random oh, couldn't really know that. But it's easily reproducible, with maximum zoom... lol.

Comment: Maximum zoom yes, but the site only supports zoom ranges of 90-110%, and browsers current and one version back, so outside of that, we're "boy who cries wolf"ing it @sha

Comment: So this might justify [tag:status-declined], not closing, in my opinion, @rand - oh and nicael is exactly that boy but guess it's not really relevant here :-)

Comment: This is fantastic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I mean...I don't even...okay. [It's fixed](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/pull/92).

> [image]

Comment: Me! Me! I have fixed the logo :) thanks for the approval!

Comment: Also, status-completed plz.

Comment: Though probably I should have also moved the top stack up a bit... That's tomorrow!

Comment: @nicael You should have probably make sure any submissions like this are 100% done and final :) Essentially you are now fixing a bug on your *own* work :D

Comment: So why no [tag:status-completed]? :)

Comment: I left it on the dev tier for a while before pushing to production. Because...you know...stunned.

Comment: Any considerations on [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/pull/99)? Because it's not really good to have all those ugly 404s.

Answer (score 11):

> There's, someone-on-the-wing, some... thing...
>
> Look at the logo:
>
> [image]
>
> Look a bit closer:
>
> [image]

---

I accept there is genuinely a fault there, but only when you zoom in to such a degree that you are no longer actually viewing the content, and are just trying to find dust with white gloves...

If you walk up to a billboard poster, and look at it from like 1 foot away, all you see is blurry coloured dots.
Should they... fix them?

---

### Let's look at it "normal-like":

[image: nothing-to-see-here]

Nuffin' wrong wi' it.

Comment: I've made a pull request anyway, fixing this stack.

Comment: I've got my request approved!!!

Comment: @nicael Nice :) Though, I think it's only done because you pushed it though Git = you've done most of the work, & they test/check & roll out. Whereas a bug report on MSE = they do *all* the work. Where possible, perhaps you should push your bug reports into git, at least then you have a chance of getting them authorised :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, for some reason that little microscopic quirk is a deliberate part of the design too - is there any specific documentation about the design, right down to the minuscule minutiae that you have highlighted?

Even if it is a 'fault', it is so outrageously insignificant, that:

a) No one notices unless you zoom in (as James' answer)
b) People generally don't care, if they notice, they are probably looking for content to read or to answer.
c) If they do notice and do care, they realise that in terms of the whole site, this kind of bug fix is a majorly low priority.

tl:dr It is so minor that it really is not a major concern

Comment: I've fixed it *anyway*.

Comment: good for you...